# not create new notification foreground android service

Tags: android, notifications, foreground, background-foreground

problem it once notification created but other notification not create and update last notification.
I want to get new notifications

call notification method :

```
 private void NotificationLoop() {

  // one notification
        G.HANDLER.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                populateNotification(1, "task id : " + 1, 20);
            }
        }, 2000);
 // two notification
        G.HANDLER.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                populateNotification(2, "task id : " + 2, 40);
            }
        }, 2000);
// three notification
        G.HANDLER.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                populateNotification(3, "task id : " + 3, 80);
            }
        }, 3000);


    }
```

populateNotification my method from service :

```
 private void populateNotification(int id, String title, int percent) {

        Notification notification;
        Intent CancelIntent = new Intent(this, ServiceDownload.class);
        CancelIntent.setAction(Constant.ACTION.CANCEL_DOANLOAD_ACTION);
        CancelIntent.putExtra("ID", id);
        PendingIntent CCancelIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, CancelIntent, 0);

        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setTicker(title)
                .setContentText(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setOngoing(false)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel, this.getResources().getString(R.string.Cancel), CCancelIntent)
                .setProgress(100, percent, false)
                .setStyle((new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(title)))
                .build();
        startForeground(id, notification);
    }
```

Comment: you startForeground same service. It looks like one service can use only one notification for startForeground. Show 2nd and 3rd notification with NotificationManager instead of startForeground in service

Answer (score 0):

Foreground Service has only one notification.

So when you call `startForeground(id, notification);` you just replace it.

You dont have much choice to solve your problem

1. Create new notification, not related to service
2. Stop foreground service and start it again, so notification will be
   exactly *new* but there is possibility, that user will not notice
   that it is new notification and not updated old notification .
3. Start new Foreground Service with new notification.